# Calculating the gradient of a scalar field. Am I missing something?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, soft-question

> **Question**
>
> Find the gradient of $f$ at each point where it exists. $f:\Bbb{R^3}
>  \to \Bbb{R} ~,~f(x,y,z)=xy^3z-\sin(x).$

**Attempted solution**

$\text{grad } f=\nabla f=(y^3z-\cos(x),3xy^2z,xy^3)$ which exists for all $(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R^3}$.

However the question where I pulled this from has indicated seven marks which seems steep for only one line of working which is making me think that I am either completely misunderstanding the question or not doing what it asks for.

Is there anyone who can say if it looks like I've missed anything?

Comment: seems fine to me

Comment: Your computation is right.  Can you post or cite the text you got the problem from?

Comment: http://imgur.com/uXAUnnx Here is a screenshot of the problem.